# Python Pandas when i add a column in an existing dataframe my new column is not correct

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am trying to get a religion adherence data visulization project done. But on my i am stuck with this problem pls help thank you

```
    x= range(1945,2011,5)
    for i in x:
       df_new= df_new.append(pd.DataFrame({'year':[i]}))
    

    years
0   1945
0   1950
0   1955
0   1960
0   1965
0   1970
0   1975
0   1980
0   1985
0   1990
0   1995
0   2000
0   2005
0   2010
```

this is my dataframe for now and i want to add a column which looks like this :

```
0     1.307603e+08
1     2.941211e+08
2     3.440720e+08
3     4.351231e+08
4     5.146341e+08
5     5.923423e+08
6     6.636743e+08
7     6.471395e+08
8     7.457716e+08
9     9.986003e+08
10    1.153186e+09
11    1.314048e+09
12    1.426454e+09
13    1.555483e+09
```

when i add them up like that

```
a=df.groupby(['year'],as_index=False)['islam'].sum()
b=a['islam']
df_new.insert(1,'islam',b)
```

the dataframe look like this which is not correct help me pls thank you !

```
    year    islam
0   1945    130760281.0
0   1950    130760281.0
0   1955    130760281.0
0   1960    130760281.0
0   1965    130760281.0
0   1970    130760281.0
0   1975    130760281.0
0   1980    130760281.0
0   1985    130760281.0
0   1990    130760281.0
0   1995    130760281.0
0   2000    130760281.0
0   2005    130760281.0
0   2010    130760281.0
```

df:

```
    year    name    christianity    judaism islam   budism  nonrelig
0   1945    USA 110265118   4641182.0   0.0 1601218 22874544
1   1950    USA 122994019   6090837.0   0.0 0   22568130
2   1955    USA 134001770   5333332.0   0.0 90173   23303540
3   1960    USA 150234347   5500000.0   0.0 2012131 21548225
4   1965    USA 167515758   5600000.0   0.0 1080892 19852362
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
1990 1990   WSM 159500  0.0 37.0    15  1200
1991 1995   WSM 161677  0.0 43.0    16  1084
1992 2000   WSM 174600  0.0 50.0    18  1500
1993 2005   WSM 177510  0.0 58.0    18  1525
1994 2010   WSM 180140  0.0 61.0    19  2750
```

Comment: what is your target result?   dataframe contains 2 columns, years & islam ,isn't it?
Do you just want to union them but not sum?

Comment: `df_new = df_new.reset_index(drop=True)` before `df_new.insert(...)`. Your indices don't match. But @ashyam's answer shows a better way to approach what you try to achieve.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny thank you for your answer but when i tried to put `df_new = df_new.reset_index(drop=True)`  before ` df_new.insert(...)` after 12nd index , instead of 13nd there was 0 so i tried to put `df_new = df_new.reset_index(drop=True)` after `df_new.insert(...)` and it is working thanks for your answer again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly assign a column to the DataFrame if the length of the list is same as the length of the DataFrame and the values are in the required order

```py
islam_values = [
    1.307603e+08,
    2.941211e+08,
    3.440720e+08,
    4.351231e+08,
    5.146341e+08,
    5.923423e+08,
    6.636743e+08,
    6.471395e+08,
    7.457716e+08,
    9.986003e+08,
    1.153186e+09,
    1.314048e+09,
    1.426454e+09,
    1.555483e+09,
]

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': list(range(1945, 2011, 5))})
df["islam"] = islam_values
```

**Output**

```
    year    islam
0   1945    1.307603e+08
1   1950    2.941211e+08
2   1955    3.440720e+08
3   1960    4.351231e+08
4   1965    5.146341e+08
5   1970    5.923423e+08
6   1975    6.636743e+08
7   1980    6.471395e+08
8   1985    7.457716e+08
9   1990    9.986003e+08
10  1995    1.153186e+09
11  2000    1.314048e+09
12  2005    1.426454e+09
13  2010    1.555483e+09
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but what if i have column with 10000 values do i need to write all the values in order to assign to a column ? Isn't there a more practical approach as i understand there is a index unmatch

Comment: Could you elaborate the scenario little more clearly? Does the main `df` has lesser/more rows than the `islam_values` list? Is that scenario you are describing?

Comment: Of course. No, `year` and  `islam` are gonna have the same amount of row.  In your answer, you created `islam_values` which you entered it's values by your hands if there was more rows isn't this method would be hard to do?

Comment: Ohh okay got it. It was just to demonstrate that you can set a column directly using a list. It can be any `list` or even a `series`. Which means you can assign any `series` or `list` to the column. For example, if the actual values of `islam_values` is in some other DataFrame (lets say `df2` under a column named `isl_vals`), you can do `df["islam"] = df2["isl_vals"]`. You can also load a excel sheet containing 10000 values of `islam_values` to a `DataFrame` or `List` and assign it to the column directly as long as the the length is same as the main DataFrame.